# Postgresql COPY command to export data to csv : Can we achieve double quotes for strings in csv's?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to export data from table to csv using COPY command. Here is my code

```
String copyQuery="COPY "+tableName+ " TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER '~' CSV HEADER";
        System.out.println(copyQuery);
        try {
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(FilePath);
                 new CopyManager((BaseConnection) conPost)
                    .copyOut(
                        copyQuery, fw
                        );
                 fw.close();
                 logger.info("postgres side csv generated");
            }
```

When I look into CSV the output is like:-
**1~vignesh~java**

But, I prefer the strings to be in double quotes :-
**1~"vignesh"~"java"**

How can I achieve this??????

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `FORCE QUOTE` and list the columns you want to wrap with double quotes:

```
COPY t TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '~' FORCE QUOTE colum2,colum3..;
```

.. or `*` to wrap all columns:

```
COPY t TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '~' FORCE QUOTE *;
```

**Demo**:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a int, b text, c text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'vignesh','java');
```

Wrapping the columns `b` and `c`:

```
COPY t TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '~' FORCE QUOTE b,c;

a~b~c
1~"vignesh"~"java"
```

Wrapping all columns:

```
COPY t TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '~' FORCE QUOTE *;

a~b~c
"1"~"vignesh"~"java"
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. But, I can't mention the specific column as I would like to compare many tables on demand. Hence, I would not prefer to have the java program specific to one table. are there any other suggestions?????

Comment: @vigneshwarreddy I don't see any reference of multiple tables in your question. Keep in mind that you export the result of a `SELECT` statement instead of a table, e.g. `COPY (SELECT * FROM t,t2 WHERE t.id=t2.id) TO STDOUT...`. But you will need to either list the columns one by one or use `*`. I'm not aware of any other option.

Comment: If we see the code I'm using tableName which is a variable I'm reading from standard input when I run the program. Based on that tableName I need to export csv's. which is the reason, I'm not able to use **FORCE QUOTE**.

Comment: @vigneshwarreddy if the table is variable and `FORCE QUTOTE *` (all columns) isn't an option for you, you'll need to write your own function for that - which shouldn't be that hard using `plpgsql`.